# get Record from DB using stored procedure in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to fetch a record from the database using a stored procedure, but it returns `null` in `SqlDataReader` object.

Here is my code:

```
public Buybest_Liberary.Data.UserManagement getUser(string email)
{
    Buybest_Liberary.Data.UserManagement obj = new Buybest_Liberary.Data.UserManagement();
    string conString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\ahmadshair\Documents\Buybest.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString);
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand("getUserRecord", connection);
    _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    _cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = email;

    SqlDataReader dr = _cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        obj.UId = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
        obj.Email = dr[1].ToString();
        obj.Password = dr[2].ToString();
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `getUserRecord`? Are you really sure it returns some data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `dr.Read()` before accessing the data! Also: put your disposable objects (`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader`) into `using(..) { ... }` blocks to ensure proper disposal:

```
public Buybest_Liberary.Data.UserManagement getUser(string email)
{
    Buybest_Liberary.Data.UserManagement obj = new Buybest_Liberary.Data.UserManagement();

    // You should read the connection string from a config file 
    // don't specify it explicitly in code!
    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["-your-connection-string-name-here-"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
    using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand("getUserRecord", connection))
    {
        _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = email;

        connection.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader dr = _cmd.ExecuteReader())
        { 
            // the SqlDataReader could return *multiple* rows - how are you
            // going to deal with that? Create an object for each row of data
            // and add them to a list to return? 
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                 obj.UId = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
                 obj.Email = dr[1].ToString();
                 obj.Password = dr[2].ToString();
            }

            dr.Close();
        }

        connection.Close();
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Also: what do you do if your stored procedure returns **multiple** rows of data? You need to somehow deal with that, too

Comment: Also, don't hard code the connection string. read it from config file. No need to call dr.Close() nor connection.Close() because dr and connection are enclosed in using blocks

Comment: @JesúsLópez: agreed - the connection string was copied from the question - not my doing. And yes - there's no *strict* need to call `dr.Close()` or `connection.Close()` - but doing so doesn't hurt, either  - I prefer to be **explicit**.

Comment: that's fine. However I think it's better to teach best practices to newcomers rather than simply answer directly the question.

Comment: Thanks, It is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

If I am not mistaken you are missing a dr.Read() to fetch the first record.

Answer (score 2):

HasRows is simply telling you whether or not there are any rows to read, whereas Read() advances the internal cursor to the next row in the data, and incidentally returns False if there are no more rows to read, or True if there was another row available.
We need dr.read()